# Use Visual Studio 2013 for web without .net

Tags: visual-studio, web

Isn't it possible to use Visual Studio for web development without attaching any .net? Even if you select an empty project, it ties in .net file associations.

Comment: Anyone got something they can add to this please?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yeah, somewhat. Moved on to use another editor. Did you have any thoughts on this or did you run into the same thing?

Comment: Same problem; I didn't find a solution

Comment: My problem is when I pick "JavaScript" project it insists I install tools for apache cordova. I don't want to use Apache Cordova, I just want a folder to put in .js, .css and .html files and be able to navigate through them easily in VS.
I could create an "empty" project in C++ but will it even see those types of files?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it the following way:

- Under C++ (yes, I know you are not going to develop in C++) create Makefile project.
- Blank out everything in the dialog that it is going to do. So it is all empty
- Rename "Header Files" "Resource Files" and "Source Files" to something appropriate like HTML files, Cascading Style Sheets and JavaScript Files
- In the properties of each, change HTML files to show html (not .html), Cascading Style Sheets to css and JavaScript Files to js.

When you create new files just use Add->New Item at the project and under Visual C++ it has Web where you can pick .html and .css (but not .js so for that use Code and just use a .js extension).

Note: you can add .php etc if you want.